# Different app language from system language

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, languages

I maybe am wanting the impossible 
I want the system to speak Dutch  but also that the apps stay speaking english

I can change the system language to Dutch but then many apps also start speaking Dutch and that I don't want

The idea behind is just a very crude safety measure at startup as non Dutch speaker you are lost so the number of potential users is severely restricted :)

While I can use English for the rest

But is this possible?

Comment: If I may, by knowing the general layout of the Android OS Settings, one intruder could change the system language with relative ease, even if the language was Chinese. Did you consider more proactive measures?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, unless it's a rooted phone. Apps will always be shown in the system language if a translation is available. English is used as a last resort. Not to mention this is a very poor security measure.

*Root option: install Xposed, look for a module named App Locale.*